# NMAP 7.94 GUI / Zenmap fails to start - Windows 10

Tags: python, nmap

After installing the current version on nmap for Windows - 7.94 the Zenmap GUI fails to start.

The Start Menu shortcut contains:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\zenmap\bin\pythonw.exe" -c "from zenmapGUI.App import run;run()"

If I append 2>error.txt to try and get a bit of feed back, error.txt contains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\zenmap\lib\python3.10\site-packages\zenmapGUI\App.py", line 73, in <module>
    import gi
  File "dist/zenmap-w64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gi: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\zenmap\lib\python3.10\site-packages\zenmapGUI\App.py", line 87, in <module>
    import gi
  File "dist/zenmap-w64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gi: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail. If I uninstall and reinstall version 7.93 all is well.

Ideas? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows installer for version 7.94 fails to properly create the shortcut.

Everything is there, but just the shortcut is broken (View GitHub issues [1](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2696) and [2](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2690)).

In order to temporary fix it, you have to manually modify the shortcut in a way that the correct Python binaries are referenced by the shortcut. On several machines I installed the tool, the fix is just changing the `Start From` property of the shortcut to point to the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\zenmap\bin`.

Note that if you chose a different installation path e.g. `D:\Nmap`, the correct path should be `D:\Nmap\zenmap\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the properties of the Zenmap shortcut: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\Zenmap.lnk".

"Start in:" was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap".  I changed it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\zenmap\bin".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).